# Some styles work in Lyx's BibTeX Generated Bibliography, others don't

Tags: bibtex, lyx, revtex

Some styles work correctly for Lyx's BibTeX Generated Bibliography, others give errors. For example, if I set the style to IEEEtran, then all is well. However, if I set it to apsrev, I get output like:

```
Runaway argument?
{{72} (\bibinfo {year}{{2012}}), ISSN \bibinfo {issn}{{0002-9505}}. \par \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@firstofone.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.397 ...Interference-Diffraction_Project_AJP_bib}

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.


Class revtex4 Warning: Endnote numbers changed: rerun LaTeX.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.


See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.399 \end{document}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Any thoughts on what I should do?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's a minimal lyx file with the problems. Plain works but the one it's set as doesn't. I'm using the latest version of MacTex; I downloaded it yesterday.

[bib file](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/bib.bib)
[lyx file](https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/test.lyx)

Comment: Hi Inmaurer, please always post your LyX version number and what OS you are using (and the OS version). It is often useful (it is in this case) to post a Minimum Working Example. Make a document that generates your error with as little other information as possible in it. And of course don't put personal information in it. And then post that.

Comment: Alrighty, I've linked to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bib.bib` file is a mess. It's not your fault -- you were given those bib entries from websites (e.g. JSTOR). However, you should clean them up. Otherwise certain bibliography styles will have trouble with them. Different bibliography styles react differently because they use different fields and they use those fields in different ways. I tested your `.lyx` file with a `.bib` file that only contained a cleaned up version of your first entry:

```
@article{Young1802,
  title = {An Account of Some Cases of the Production of Colours, not Hitherto Described},
  author = {Young, Thomas},
  journal = {Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London},
  volume = {92},
  number = {},
  pages = {pp. 387-397},
  language = {English},
  year = {1802},
  publisher = {The Royal Society}
}
```

And it worked fine. So clean up your `.bib` and add in the new entries one by one to make sure you can figure out which entry is the one that is causing problems.

Also note in the following that the ampersands should probably be escaped (put a backslash before them):

```
publisher = {Taylor & Francis, Ltd.},
copyright = {Copyright © 2005 Taylor & Francis, Ltd.}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I wish things like the url field wouldn't trip it up.

Comment: @Inmaurer yeah I agree that it can be very sensitive. And the errors are sometimes cryptic.